# React Native Data Types

Tags: reactjs, react-native, types, native

Can we determine the data type (string, integer, boolean, etc.) of variables using react native?

For example:

```
class ex {
  years: integer;
  name: string;
  remember: boolean;
}
```

Can I decide whether the data from the form is a string or an integer?

Comment: Yes, of course, you can use `prop-types` for type checking.

Comment: I want to specify state data types that are not prop

Comment: Arent you missing the javascript tag? This mostly depends on the language, not framework.

Comment: i'm newbeen and how i don't know do it

Answer (score 5):

yes you can find type of a variable using **`typeof(your variable name)`**
Example

```
var name="name here";
console.log("type of variable is:"+typeof(name));
```

**output**

> type of variable is: string